# How can I avoid warnings when checking element in array for numeric equivalency to zero even though some elements are character strings?

Tags: perl

I would like to not get the warning that the value being checked isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) when checking for the number zero in an array of arrays that includes character string elements and numeric elements.

I am working with an array of arrays (aoa) in Perl.  Some elements in the aoa are character strings and some are numeric.  I need to check if the element $aoa[$i][$j] is the number zero.  I am using this code.

```
if($aoa[$i][$j] == '0'){
    next;
}
```

This produces tons of warnings (one for each check on a character element - my data has several hundred thousand elements to check) that the "argument isn't numeric in numeric eq (==)".
I want to not see these warnings.  Other than specifically suppress this warning at this point in my code, can I do my check any differently such that it will not produce these warnings at this step?

This isn't so much to make my code work better for my task, it is simply to stop getting a ton of warnings that make you think something isn't working correctly in the code.  When you tell someone, "oh, don't worry about all those warnings - it is working fine" some people tend to not believe you!

Comment: Have you tried string comparison [`eq`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators)?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Yes, I did try string comparison (eq).  It unfortunately didn't capture the zero values.

Comment: I wonder if `int('0.0') eq '0'` is relevant here.  But be careful with `int(undef)` and `int(\z)`.

Comment: You could also use `no warnings 'numeric';` in a limited scope if you are sure you want non-numeric data to be truncated to a number or treated as 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, there are several ways to do it. If none of your elements are `undef`, then you can test for falseness and `ne ''`, as in `if (!$x && $x ne '') {}` (using $x for brevity). That won't catch certain expressions of zero, such as "0E0" or "0 but true". If those matter to you, then another approach is to use the `looks_like_number()` function from the standard `Scalar::Util` module. That way you can say `if (looks_like_number($x) && $x == 0) {}` without fear of warnings. You could also simply say `if ($x eq '0') {}` if you're sure that your zeros are in normal form, because it's valid to do a string comparison against a number (but not vice versa).

Good for you wanting to eliminate warnings, by the way.

Comment: I am going to mark this answer as the accepted answer only because of the considerations for the 'type' of zero.  I think both this answer and @Dave Cross's answer are both perfect answers though.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `looks_like_number()` (from [Scalar::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util)):

```
use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';

if (looks_like_number($aoa[$i][$j]) and $aoa[$i][$j] == '0'){
    next;
}
```

Or something like this:

```
# If the value has a length and is false, then it
# must be 0 or 0.0.
if (length($aoa[$i][$j]) and ! $aoa[$i][$j]) {
    next;
}
```

Comment: I ended up using the Scalar::Util looks_like_number() version and it works perfectly for me.  Thank you.  I wish I could mark two answers as 'correct'.